# Passing variable to FindsBy selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, htmlelements

I want to pass variable to element. My html is like

```
<input class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: code, attr: { id: 'myTable_code_' + $index() }" type="text" id="myTable_code_0" style="">
```

I declared element like

```
  [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "myTable_code_" + myVariable), CacheLookup]
  private HtmlElement _Code;
```

But offcourse that is not working. Has anyone idea on how to pass varialbe to attribute. I am using c#

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, Annotations are constant values stored in the class file. You can't compute them at runtime.

Below should work:-
    Using = "myTable_code_0")

See [Can the annotation variables be determined at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743167/can-the-annotation-variables-be-determined-at-runtime)?

Though, it is for java, but i think it hold true for C# also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using finds by, how about string format? You will need to adjust this a bit based on your setup but depending on what you want to do with the value, you could do something like this...

```
        string myVariable = "blah";
        string value =  Browser.FindElement_byXPath(string.Format("//input[@id='myTable_code_0']//h4[contains(text(), '{0}')]", myVariable)).Text;
```